# Grayscale stacked area plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a stacked area plot in R using the `stackpoly()` command in the plotrix package. The default colors are glaring, to say the least. Is there any way to use symbols or grayscale instead?

Comment: Please provide a working example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `?stackpoly`:

```
 col: Color to fill the polygons. If NULL, ‘rainbow’ will be called
      to generate the colors. If NA, the polygons will not be
      filled.
```

Slightly modifying the example in `?stackpoly`:

```
stackpoly(matrix(cumsum(testx),nrow=10),main="Test Stackpoly I",
   xaxlab=c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"),
  border="black",staxx=TRUE,
col=gray(seq(0.1,0.9,length=10)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you.  If I may be snarky for just a moment: you could perhaps have found this answer for yourself by searching the ?stackpoly page for "color" ...

Comment: I should have spotted it, but didn't. Apologies for sloppy research. My appreciation stands.